# Using domain alias instead of host name in kerberos authentication

Tags: java, dns, alias, kerberos, gssapi

I use java GSS-API with kerberos. It works fine when I use host name like:

ldapUrl = ldap://myhost.mydomain.net

But when I user like:

```
ldapUrl = ldap://mydomain.net
```

it produces error: Server not found in Kerberos database.
But mydomain.net is domain alias that present a pool of host.
If I will select separate host from pool and use - works, when use alias - doesn't.
What the reason?

Comment: That only works with Reverse DNS. You cannot register the realm name as SPN.